# Mobile app / Yii2 Rest api and Facebook login

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I would like to create a Yii2 rest api, to be consumed by a mobile application.

The user should login in the application, using facebook account and gain access to the rest api.

In my database I have the default Yii User table, with an extra column: TOKEN char(32).

What I did until now:
Mobile:
1 - User open the mobile application;
2 - Log in using Facebook account;

Yii2 Framework:
1 - Create a yii2 rest api, based on: http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/ (return countries);

But, whats next?

Shoul I receive a Token from Facebook?
Send this Token to my Rest Api? How? Do I have to use: findIdentityByAccessToken implemented in User model?
Do I have to save this token in the user table?
Is this Token returned by facebook static, or is temporary?
Should I compare the user permission, only using this Token using ssl? Or I have to implment Ouath2 in my Yii environment? Cz Facebook already did this validation, I don't know.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through the same scenario once. What I did was:

1. Let your user login into your Yii website and let him to connect his facebook account from settings panel. Get access token, expiry time, facebook ID etc. and store them in some table with mapping to User ID and Email ID.
2. Now you have access token for your user. Make user login into your mobile app. Make him login via facebook. Get access token after login.
3. Now send this token with each request via api call and using this token in your Yii app, get the user details calling Facebook SDK with this token. If token is valid, you will get user profile with Email id, facebook id, etc.
4. Check the email or facebook ID from your table and see if any User exists. If User exists that means he is authorized user and process the request and respond with data. If user does not exists that means either he hasn't connected his account or he is trying to login via invalid facebook account.
5. Also, store the access token in your app locally and validate at Yii server for each request if it is expired or not. If expired, send some response to identify action and get new access token from your app.

The  above solution worked for me like a charm. Check it out.
Also you can set up your own Outh 2.0 server for your existing Yii app. Check out from these [links](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Yp2YV96DIavT8gez7pqwCw&gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=yii2%20oauth%20server).

Hope this helps you (or) someone. :)